# Wordpress/API/Twitter to bring latest tweet inside my Wordpress doesnt' work, I get error 404 couldn't retrieve tweets

Tags: wordpress, twitter, get, local

I'm using local Wordpress to test my plugin but it doesn't work  for some reason, I do have the consumer/access just wrote ??? to hide sensitive info.
What happens is that it responds with error code 404, I'm not sure if its the code that's not working or if it is some type of settings I need to change to make it work.

[image]

I have tried the most things but right now I am on a dead end without any further progress.

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Social media crawler
Description:  ???
Version:      1.0
Author:       ???
License:      GPL2
License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Domain Path:  /languages
*/



require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

function my_twitter_feed_function() {

    // Set up your Twitter API credential
    $consumer_key = '???';
    $consumer_secret = '???';
    $access_token = '???';
    $access_token_secret = '???';

    // Set up the connection
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);

    // The Twitter handle of the user you want to retrieve tweets from
    $twitterHandle = 'eldoradotest';
    $tweets = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", ["screen_name" => $twitterHandle, "count" => 1, "exclude_replies" => true]);

    $output = '';

    // Check for errors
    if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
        // Loop through the tweets and build the output
        foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
            $output .= '<div class="tweet">' . $tweet->text . '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        // Handle errors more robustly
        $errorBody = $connection->getLastBody();
        if ($errorBody && isset($errorBody->errors) && is_array($errorBody->errors)) {
            $output .= "Failed to retrieve tweets: " . $errorBody->errors[0]->message;
        } else {
            $output .= "Failed to retrieve tweets. Error code: " . $connection->getLastHttpCode();
        }
    }


    return $output;
}


add_shortcode('my_twitter_feed', 'my_twitter_feed_function');
```

Comment: Can't tell which API version this is using, but if it is v2, the endpoints have changed: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/migrate